# WebRTC + Media Server = End-to-End Encrypted?

Tags: webrtc

I've got a peer-to-peer WebRTC connection all set up on my service.  It's fantastic.

I'm now looking to move on to group chats that will surely involve more than half-dozen people. 
 I know this requires a media server.

But do media servers preserve the same end-to-end encryption as peer-to-peer connections?  If data is just being passed through the server and distributed to multiple people I could imagine it's possible that it's still encrypted.  But all the media servers that I see do other fancy things like record the stream.  And I can't imagine how that's done in an end-to-end encrypted way (where the media server can't actually view the data that is being passed through it).

So is it possible to have end-to-end encryption with a media server in the same way that it's possible with a simple peer-to-peer connection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes!

It is brand new, but WebRTC is adding E2E Encryption via the [Insertable Streams](https://webrtchacks.com/true-end-to-end-encryption-with-webrtc-insertable-streams/) API.

The browser will have a callback so you can process the data yourself. You can encrypt before it is sent to the media server (or do other processing).

Comment: Thanks so much for this information!  What I read from this is that my understanding/assumption was correct.  That media servers cannot be end-to-end encrypted at this time.  But soon/now it will be possible with this new thing.